# Apache / PHP Docker containers are just serving the PHP source files and not executing the PHP files correctly

Tags: php, docker, apache

I'm trying to run a Laravel app in my local environment via Docker. I want to setup separate containers for each service i.e. Apache, PHP, MySQL. I also want to keep Composer, Artisan and PHPUnit in separate containers as well. This is more for neatness than anything else.

All the containers spin up with no issues and I can access each one no problems via the 'docker-compose exec [container name] /bin/sh' command.

The problem I'm having is that the index.php in the public folder is not being executed correctly. Apache is just serving up the file contents.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried using an Nginx container instead of Apache but I get the same issue. I'm guessing my Apache container does not recognize my PHP container.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong below?

My docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  cpw:
    name: cpw_network

services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apache.dockerfile
    container_name: cpw_apache
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - cpw

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: cpw_php
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - cpw

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.32
    container_name: cpw_mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: cpw
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    networks:
      - cpw

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: cpw_composer
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    networks:
      - cpw

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: cpw_artisan
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: [ "php", "artisan" ]
    networks:
      - cpw

  phpunit:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: cpw_phpunit
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: [ "/var/www/html/vendor/bin/phpunit" ]
    networks:
      - cpw
```

My apache.dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM httpd:alpine

ADD ./apache/httpd-vhosts.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

RUN sed -i 's,#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf,Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf,g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
```

My php.dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM php:7.4.12-fpm-alpine
      
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
        
RUN apk --no-cache add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data
        
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog logs/localhost-error_log
    CustomLog logs/localhost-access_log common

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.php
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? I don't see any configuration that tells Apache to use the PHP container for anything

Comment: @NicoHaase, I've tried to use the Nginx container instead of Apache.

Comment: And where's the configuration for Apache that instructs the server to use PHP?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862387/how-to-deploy-php-fpm-on-docker-container-and-apache-nginx-on-localhost-ubuntu help?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the exact difference between this question and [the one you posted earlier that got closed and you decided to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66319445/apache-php-docker-containers-are-just-serving-the-php-source-files-and-not-exe) ? If you decide to deliberately not follow the rules, you could at the very least rework your question to show us you have made some progress.

Comment: @Zeitounator there's no difference, I've added more detail to this one as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @NicoHaase for pointing me in the right direction.

This is the piece I was missing:

```
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php-fpm-container:9000"
  </FilesMatch>
```

More details here:

[How to deploy php-fpm on docker container and apache/nginx on localhost (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862387/how-to-deploy-php-fpm-on-docker-container-and-apache-nginx-on-localhost-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been trying to resolve the same issue for 3 days in a row, my mind almost melted!

Comment: And where does the name php-fpm-container come from?

Comment: where should I add these text?

Answer (score 0):

This might also fix:

```
<FilesMatch \.(?i:php)$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```