# Docker: How can I run a Wordpress project with specific versions?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I'm trying to run a Wordpress project with mysql 5.5.68, Wordpress 5.7.2, Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) and PHP 7.3.28 with Docker.
The containers are up and running and I can access them but when I try to visit `localhost:8000` the page doesn't load. I see `This page isn't working ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

What do I need to add/modify to my `docker-compose.yml` file to get my project to run?

docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: '3'
 
 services:
   # Database
   db:
     image: mysql:5.5
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     networks:
       - wpsite
   # phpmyadmin
   phpmyadmin:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     restart: always
     ports:
       - '8080:80'
     environment:
       PMA_HOST: db
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
     networks:
       - wpsite
   # Wordpress
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:php7.3-fpm-alpine
     ports:
       - '8000:80'
     restart: always
     volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     networks:
       - wpsite
 networks:
   wpsite:
 volumes:
   db_data:
```

Comment: The easy solution is to use `wordpress:php7.3` rather than `wordpress:php7.3-fpm-alpine`

Comment: @HansKilian i'm going to go with `wordpress:5.7.2-php7.3-apache`. Its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the image you are using for your core wordpress applicaiton `wordpress:php7.3-fpm-alpine` does not include a reverse proxy / web server to actually serve your site.

This is backed up by the documentation on the wordpress image page here: https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress in the 'Image Varient' section you will see this comment:

> wordpress:-fpm.
> This variant contains PHP-FPM, which is a FastCGI implementation for PHP. See the PHP-FPM website for more information about PHP-FPM.
> In order to use this image variant, some kind of reverse proxy (such as NGINX, Apache, or other tool which speaks the FastCGI protocol) will be required.

Find an image with an included Web Server / Reverse Proxy, or use a Reverse Proxy like NGINX. The link above has some liks to resources to implement this =)

---

*Added after initial answer submission*

You've specified your Apache version, but not included it within your compose setup. You'll need to add an apache container ([called httpd on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)) and configure it with either a copied in config file, or volume mount one into the apache container.

This post has some details on the configuration you'll need to add to pass the PHP handling over to FPM: wordpress:-fpm https://stackoverflow.com/a/66234290/5889983

Comment: Thanks! you pointed me in the right direction. I tried `wordpress:5.7.2-php7.3-apache` and its working.

Comment: wordpress:php7.3-fpm-alpine already contains the wordpress static files in /var/www/html. Does the reverse proxy (running on a different container) need to call the wordpress:php7.3-fpm-alpine container that has the wordpress static files?