# Deploy Docker PHP-FPM with Apache on Host (Windows) Giving 404

Tags: php, docker, apache

I have apache installed on my windows machine with locally installed PHP 8 on it. now for a single project I need 5.6 (don't blame me customer is not ready to move on). So I install a `php-fpm-alpine` docker on my machine and configure the `.htaccess` in my project folder to attach to that fpm.
It works in sense that I can see all request been logged in my Docker Log, but it is not finding the file. and hence cannnot execute it.

my apache configuration is simple.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000/www/var/html$1"
</FilesMatch>
```

my docker gives 2 option to set /var/www/html to my windows folder that I configure correctly as I can go in command line of docker and can do `ls /var/www/html` and it shows all project file with `www-data` user fine. and port is working too.

I believe the PHP-fpm is not using the folder define by /var/www/html properly and looking somewhere else but I have no idea where to check.

Comment: I have a similar scenario working and my Apache config omits the path. Have you tried SetHandler without "/www/var/html$1"?

Comment: I did, if I put it as localhost:9000 it take full `E:\..`, if I use `localhost:9000\ ` or anything after \ it take my path as `\<foldername>` no matter what.